# Creating script to login muliple vendors that do not have API's, How can I do this with php since I will need user sessions?

Tags: php, session, authentication, forms-authentication

Ok, We are a large reseller of auto parts. We need to login( different logins for each and different domains) to 15 different vendors websites to obtain information about products by searching there SKU to receive pricing information and stock. All sites use typical searching structures( etc. /search?SKU=FSA9FSDF ) so making the script automate the search per vendor could be coded, although website redesigns will cause issues here and there. Pulling the pricing and stock info and assigning to variables shouldn't be an issue either.

**Here is what our developer is telling us the issue will be**

> To automate this process of pulling product price from vendor sites, we would need to have   > access to their api or some sort of endpoints which can be called directly from within a    > script. 
>   With login page, it cannot be automated as the session cookie will be required to validate  > the login status of user.

There are no API's for most sites. There must be some way to do this, as its extremely time consuming and costly to have our staff do this, and causes errors from time to time.

We also can use other programming languages to achieve this if necessary.

Comment: You would need to use CURL requests to mimic a user logging in. The problem is alot of companies monitor activity like high usage of their pages from one IP source because automated scripts that request alot of pages at a time bog down system resources. It is possible they will lock you out eventually unless they have given you permission.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your developer is correct.  When endpoints and/or APIs do not exist, we usually have to resort to screen-scraping, pulling information out of emails, or seeing if the third-party systems can drop a "search file" at an FTP or WEBDAV location, where *your* application would then poll that FTP or WEBDAV location with some frequency acceptable to you and your workflows.

We've been through this ourselves, but in a different industry: construction.

Also, it is a good idea to call each of these vendors to find out what they offer.  You might be surprised to find out that they have been, or are, working on exposing their data in some way.  At a minimum, they may have DVD-based databases.  It's a little old-fashioned, but generally a piece of cake to import data in this scenario.

One last suggestion: There may be a third party out there (by "third" I mean a party completely different to any of your vendors) who aggregates this data and offers some sort of data product.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact the vendors, hope they will accomodate, I would air on the side of caution and not discuss scraping options; but I think by the sounds of the situation, your best bet will be to get in an automation expert who you can build links with to speed up and improve accuracy in the process. Having a computer do something can be hundreds of thousands of times faster than people following the same process and although computers and programming cost, they typically are only in place because they save money.

Not all programmers will be up for the task and hundreds of applicants will probably have little proficiency in scraping content, workarounds etc. I would suggest being quiet about scraping sites as it can get you banned. Let's face it some vendors cannot see the opportunity. I Even had to help one E-commerce customer to scrape his product images, descriptions, youtube video's and dimensions from his site in 2013 because a nasty ERP vendor would not give access to the information in a meaningful way... Sadly this is the world we live in.

If you did get a real programmer, they will likely need to be put on retainer after the initial project to keep up with changes to the external service(s), but if the third-parties want all traffic to go through them and do not want to provide an API, this is likely still the best option when compared to minimum wage.

Shawns comments are also valid, but if you get a scraper that knows what they are doing, you have little to fear as they will have tools to make things look genuine!

Hope this helps